# How do I perform an OR search on jQuery attributes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-attributes

I have a bunch of `li` items that have some custom attributes:

```
<ul>
  <li count="1">foo</li>
  <li count="1">foo1</li>
  <li count="*">foo2</li>
  <li>foobar</li>
  <li count="0">bar2</li>
  <li count="*">bar3</li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to select those `li` elements that have an attribute `count` with a value of 1 or 0.  Can I do this without performing 2 selections?

I can see how I can perform an AND selection in order to narrow down results (e.g. `$("li[count='0'][otherAttr='blah']")...`).  But I'm not sure if you can perform an OR selection.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a number of ways, but you'll need to use a comma:

```
$("li[count='0'], li[count='1']")...
```

Or, my preferred method...

```
$("li").filter("[count='1'], [count='0']")...
```

Comment: Why do you prefer that way?  Is it just cleaner for you to read, or is there a performance edge to it?

Comment: It's just cleaner to read. I just benchmarked it and by NOT using filter, (method 1) you actually save some function calls. But if you have a large DOM with an unspecific selector, using filter (method 2) will be faster (ever so slightly, of course).

Comment: Thanks.  That's an interesting perspective.  That helps.

Answer (score 3):

Use comma

```
 $("li[count='0'], li[otherAttr='blah']")....
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use `li[count*='01']` ?

Comment: Using `[attribute*='string']` will select items that have attributes which "contain" string, NOT attributes that contain each individual letter: s, t, r, i, n, g.